# how to understand the それ+X differences

Tags: words

I'm trying to understand when to use each それ[X] word, so i search on google and came out with this list:

```
それに: in addition, also (それも＝それに)
そして: and,and then,and now
それから: and then, after that
それで: and, thereupon, because of that⁠⁠⁠⁠
それでも - but, and yet, nevertheless, even so
それでは; それじゃ - well then ... , in that situation...
```

The last two I manage to pick up, it's quite a bit like でも and じゃ...but I'm having a problem to pick up the differences between the first four words.

Thanks for the help,
Or

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the following sources:
A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar (DBJG)
A Dictionary of Intermediate Japanese Grammar (DIJG)

それに: a conjunction that introduces an additional item or element. (DIJG, pag 427)
そして: a coordinate conjunction that connects two sentences. (DBJG, pag 422)
それから: a conjunction that indicates (1) temporally contiguous actions or states, or (2) a cumulative listing of objects, actions or states. (DBJG, page 416)
それで：a conjunction to indicate that what is stated in the preceding sentence is the reason or cause for what is stated in the following sentence. (DBJG, page 413)

So each word has a slightly different meaning and usage, even though they may be translated to English similarly.
You should study the usage of each word separately.

Comment: Thanks you. Tell me, DBJG and DIJG have an example sentences with the explanation? sounds like a book worth buying

Comment: @Smiled_One Invaluable books. Plenty of examples. I couldn't live without them. There's also a Dictionary of Advanced Japanese Grammar.